# Loading gltf/glb without textures/colors issue using GLTF loader

Tags: three.js, 3d, gltf

First of all - I AM A BEGINNER in **Three.js**. By creating this question I want to leave the information on how to solve that issue when loaded gltf models do not have textures.
[image]

```js
const loader = new GLTFLoader();
loader.load(
    // resource URL
    // PVPanelDataURI,
    process.env.PUBLIC_URL + 'staticPresets/PVPanel.gltf',
    (gltf) => {
        this.scene.add(gltf.scene);
        console.log('gltf', gltf)
    },
    function(xhr) {
        console.log((xhr.loaded / xhr.total * 100) + '% loaded');
    },
    function(error) {
        console.log('An error happened: ', error);
    }
);
```

Also, I would like to get rid of that warning:
[image]

I will be grateful for the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a lot of reasons for that. You can even have a broken GLTF file sometimes. But if **you are lucky** then you need to create light for your model and all will be alright!

```js
const ambientLight = new AmbientLight(0xFFFFFF);
ambientLight.intensity = 4;
this.scene.add( ambientLight );
```

[image]

Notice that sometimes intensity must be significant and light should be different. I used

```js
const spotLight = new THREE.SpotLight( 0xffffff );
spotLight.intensity = 10;
spotLight.position.set( 1000, 1000, 1000 );
```

to be able to see the black surface of my model. Also, you may need to navigate around on a canvas to see the difference.
[image]